# jQuery toggle with addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code, where you click on a div and it adds a class to another.

```
$("#mydiv").click(function() {

    $('#div').toggle();
    $('#div').addClass('animated bounceInDown');

});
```

What I need to do is integrate it into the toggle where when I click the 1st time I add classes **'animated bounceInDown'** and when I click the second time I replace those Classes with **'animated bounceInUp'**

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) ?

Comment: Use a counter, increase it on every click, check if counter is odd `do this` else `do that`

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize there was a toggleClass :/

Comment: @Satch3000, And it works with multiple classes and `second` argument as `state`

Comment: It's just like that but with a twist ... When I click once, I'm also making the div hide / show .... So, 1st click = show and add someclass , 2nd click = hide and add someotherclass

Comment: @Satch3000, You can have classes like `show/hide`

Comment: Yeah good point ... so toggleClass('hideme animated bounceInDown')   ... then 3 other classes ... can that be done?

Comment: But because you are using `toggle()`, at some point (odd or even click), the element is hidden so there is no point to animate it. I'm really not sure to understand your expected behaviour here?!

Comment: I need the both animations ... One to show and the other to hide

Comment: @Satch3000 And so what is the point of using `toggle()` in your code?

Comment: @Satch3000 Can you provide a jsFiddle? i'm sure someone would fix your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#mydiv").click(function() {
  //toggle the class on the current button
  //just to keep the state
  var mydiv = $(this).toggleClass("toggled");

  $('#div')
    .addClass('animated')
    .toggleClass(function() {
    //depending on the state of #mydiv, return
    //different classes
      return mydiv.hasClass("toggled")
        ? 'bounceInDown' 
        : 'bounceInUp' 
  });
});
```

Comment: Why are you using `mydiv` variable? And anyway as i can see it, this will remove `animated` class which then doesn't animate element

Comment: You are right @A. Wolff  ... no animation is happening here

Comment: @A.Wolff im caching mydiv to get its' state in toggleClass closure (and using it as a state storage, adding/removing 'toggle' class)

Comment: @Satch3000 try now, accidently added 'animate' class previously. But im not sure if your approach to setting animation is correct. The code works as expected though.